# What is the purpose of the DENY section (SID 3) in AWS Elastic Transcoder default policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, policy

I am looking at the default policy (below) and I do not understand why the section identified as SID 3 is necessary.  By default permissions are denied unless they are allowed.  I don't see that the previous sections (SID 1 and SID 2) allow the actions that are denied in SID 3.  Am I missing something?  It doesn't hurt to explicitly set these denials but I think they are unnecessary.

```
{
    "Version" : "2008-10-17",
    "Statement" : [{
            "Sid" : "1",
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Action" : ["s3:Put*", "s3:ListBucket", "s3:*MultipartUpload*", "s3:Get*"],
            "Resource" : "*"
        }, {
            "Sid" : "2",
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Action" : "sns:Publish",
            "Resource" : "*"
        }, {
            "Sid" : "3",
            "Effect" : "Deny",
            "Action" : ["s3:*Delete*", "s3:*Policy*", "sns:*Remove*", "sns:*Delete*", "sns:*Permission*"],
            "Resource" : "*"
        }
    ]
```